# Cargo maven plugin problem on hudson release

Tags: java, jboss, maven, hudson, cargo

i'm trying to setup hudson job to release out project. I have one problem with cargo maven plugin. On release:prepare and release:perform it runs twice our integration tests. To run integration tests we unpack our artifact with jboss, then we deploy ear to our instance run tests, then stop instance, undeploy our ear. On this step everything is ok. But when doing second run cargo maven plugin fails with such an error:

```
  [INFO] [ERROR] FATAL ERROR
  [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] [INFO] Failed to create a JBoss 4.2.3 existing configuration
  ..
  The required web context is already in use by another application.
  [INFO]    at     org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractCopyingInstalledLocalDeployer.deploy(AbstractCopyingInstalledLocalDeployer.java:139)
  [INFO]    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractDeployer.deploy(AbstractDeployer.java:48)
  [INFO]    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBossExistingLocalConfiguration.doConfigure(JBossExistingLocalConfiguration.java:84)
  [INFO]    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.configuration.AbstractLocalConfiguration.configure(AbstractLocalConfiguration.java:190)
```

So i guess the problem itself is in :The required web context is already in use by another application. Maybe someone had similar issue with webcontext?

Answer (score 1):

I had such an issue. I had 2 applications. When I checked the **META-INF/context.xml** file, I saw that the **path** attribute of **Context** tag was same for both applications. When each application had different context value, the problem had gone. I hope it helps for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but was related to cargo plugin version.

Error exhibited

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
```

Works correctly

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
```